# rake aborted! No such file or directory after write admin.css

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, amazon-ec2, sprockets, precompile

I deploy rails code to EC2 using Capistrano

But I met same problems while run

```
cd -- /home/stage_deployer/urbox/releases/20140306102215 && RAILS_ENV=staging RAILS_GROUPS=assets bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

Below is the command I debug at EC2

```
stage_deployer@ip-172-31-5-59:~/urbox/releases/test$ RAILS_ENV=staging RAILS_GROUPS=assets
```

Below are the log

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile --trace
** Invoke assets:precompile (first_time)
** Invoke assets:environment (first_time)
** Execute assets:environment
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
I, [2014-03-06T10:33:54.388029 #11702]  INFO -- : ** [Raven] Raven 0.6.0 ready to catch errors
AssetSync: using /home/stage_deployer/test/releases/test/config/initializers/asset_sync.rb
** Execute assets:precompile
...
...
I, [2014-03-06T10:34:04.551896 #11702]  INFO -- : Writing /home/stage_deployer/urbox/releases/test/public/assets/admin.js
I, [2014-03-06T10:34:04.553847 #11702]  INFO -- : Writing /home/stage_deployer/urbox/releases/test/public/assets/application.js
I, [2014-03-06T10:34:04.554514 #11702]  INFO -- : Writing /home/stage_deployer/urbox/releases/test/public/assets/ckeditor/config.js
I, [2014-03-06T10:34:04.554819 #11702]  INFO -- : Writing /home/stage_deployer/urbox/releases/test/public/assets/admin.css
rake aborted!
No such file or directory - /home/stage_deployer/urbox/releases/test/public/assets/admin-c503a9b1f76de48a2717d7ff8581fe74.css
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:1551:in `stat'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:1551:in `block in fu_each_src_dest'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:1567:in `fu_each_src_dest0'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:1549:in `fu_each_src_dest'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:393:in `cp'
/home/stage_deployer/urbox/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/non-stupid-digest-assets-1.0.0/lib/non-stupid-digest-assets.rb:10:in `block in compile_with_non_digest'
/home/stage_deployer/urbox/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/non-stupid-digest-assets-1.0.0/lib/non-stupid-digest-assets.rb:6:in `each'
/home/stage_deployer/urbox/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/non-stupid-digest-assets-1.0.0/lib/non-stupid-digest-assets.rb:6:in `compile_with_non_digest'
/home/stage_deployer/urbox/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.0.1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:60:in `block (3 levels) in define'
/home/stage_deployer/urbox/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.1/lib/rake/sprocketstask.rb:146:in `with_logger'
/home/stage_deployer/urbox/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.0.1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:59:in `block (2 levels) in define'
/home/stage_deployer/urbox/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:236:in `call'
/home/stage_deployer/urbox/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:236:in `block in execute'
/home/stage_deployer/urbox/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:231:in `each'
/home/stage_deployer/urbox/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:231:in `execute'
/home/stage_deployer/urbox/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:175:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/home/stage_deployer/urbox/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:168:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/stage_deployer/urbox/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:161:in `invoke'
/home/stage_deployer/urbox/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:149:in `invoke_task'
/home/stage_deployer/urbox/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/home/stage_deployer/urbox/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
/home/stage_deployer/urbox/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
/home/stage_deployer/urbox/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
/home/stage_deployer/urbox/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
/home/stage_deployer/urbox/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
/home/stage_deployer/urbox/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:165:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/stage_deployer/urbox/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/home/stage_deployer/urbox/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/home/stage_deployer/urbox/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/home/stage_deployer/urbox/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
```

This problem is happened after I try to add some resource of crumble.js under **vender/stylesheets/crumble/grumble.min.css** and **vender/stylesheets/crumble/crumble.css**

grumble.min.css https://github.com/tommoor/crumble/blob/master/css/grumble.min.css
crumble.css https://github.com/tommoor/crumble/blob/master/css/crumble.css

Please help me~~

I try to run

```
rake assets:precompile
```

in local machine, but no occur any problems

here is my admin.css

```
/*
 *= require twitter/bootstrap
 *= require select2
 *= require bootstrap-editable
 *= require unicorn.main
 *= require unicorn.grey
 *= require jquery.ui.datepicker
 *= require_self
*/

.sortable-item {
  background: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #b5b5b5;
  border-bottom-width: 2px;
  background-image: none;
  margin: 0 0 3px 0;
  padding: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 30px;
  list-style: none;
}

td.center { text-align: center; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should update your `non-stupid-asset-digest` gem.

It's at version `1.0.4` now and has better error handling around the case where there are missing files. This will allow you to get your site up.

Once you're up and running, then you can look at the logs/file system and investigate why some of the digests aren't being generated.

Let me know whether this helps.

Comment: hello, crumble is based on grumble. I can run the code successfully in local machine. So, I think, this might be a asset compile problem in EC2?